# Types of techniques used in each testing method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, system-testing

I have been research on what is unit testing, integration testing and system testing.

I am writing a thesis on an exam system I am creating using php, jquery, javascript and mysqli programming. It is basically an exam system which connects to the database where the teachers are able to create exams and students take the created exams.

Anyway what my question is that does anyone have an examples or know any useful websites of different techniques to use to be able to fulfil these types of testing methods. If you can name these procedures then I will be more than happy to research those methods and be able to include those in my testing methods in my thesis.

When you provide an example or name the techniques, can you state if they are either unit testing, integration testing and system testing.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This seems like a survey. It does not sit right with me to do your research for your thesis.

Comment: line coverage; clause coverage; predicate coverage; input space coverage; path coverage; etc... etc... etc...

Comment: This does not seem the right format for SO. Seems like doing "homework" or as paul put it, a survey. SO questions should be answerable and more focused... sorry user1490145, i've downvoted you :(

Comment: Hi, I just wanted just list of different techniques experience web programmers use when they test their websites. I will do all the research, I just need names of techniques like Sam I am has provided so I can research them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at that, I think it will be helpful for you: http://www.istqb.org/downloads

Go to Foundation Level Documents -> Foundation Level Syllabus (2011)